# Файлы с другого сайта на одном сервере

Tags: php, сервер

Есть 2 сайта лежащие на одном сервере
var/www/site/
var/www/model/
Один типа фронта, на втором загружены 3д модели.
Можно ли как-то прописать относительный пути на сайте "site", чтобы на нем грузились модели с сайта "model"?
Если просто вбить путь типа src="http://model/path/to/3dmodel", консоль бьет ошибку
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
https сертификата нету.

Comment: Настройте свой веб сервер, а так же прочитайте данную статью https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант сделать через симлинки.

```
cd var/www/site/
ln -s var/www/model/path/to/ models
```

и по идее должно быть доступно по http://site/models/3dmodel